# FOS User Change Password Event Listener

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with a listening event on change password submit.

Here is listener

```
public function __construct(
    UrlGeneratorInterface $router,
    Session $session,
    TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
) {
    $this->router = $router;
    $this->session = $session;
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_SUCCESS => [
            ['onChangePasswordSuccess', +10000]
        ],
    ];
}

public function onChangePasswordSuccess(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
{
    $this->tokenStorage->setToken(); // logout user
    $this->session->invalidate();
    $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('fos_user_security_login')));
}
```

But nothing happens. I put debugger breakpoint on $this->tokenStorage->setToken() but it wasn't stop. 
Could somebody help me to figure why this not working

Comment: Have you registered this listener in `services.yml`? Can you show it's configuration?

Comment: CoreBundle\EventListener\ChangePasswordListener:
     tags:
       - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
First I put this but and it didn't work. Then I removed because I use autowire and also didn't work

Comment: I guess you should add something like this inside your services configuration.. https://gist.github.com/kaduev13/b569ed0d53af70a4bc697bf7ee88c8bc

Comment: Also, check please, that this `services.yml` is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha. I loked in wrong controller. When I found right, everything worked as it should. Thanks Ivan for your help